# Jenkins Pipeline MissingPropertyException for Working Powershell Command

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run this working script in my Jenkins Pipeline build:

```
powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "gci -path "c:/jenkins/workspace/testdata" -recurse | where-object{ $_.Name -like "*testconfig.staging.json*"} | %{rename-item $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace("staging","local") }")
```

However this gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
```

I've tried cutting up the command to see where it fails and it seems to happen when I try to pipe my output to `where-object`.

If I just run this:

```
powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "gci -path "c:/jenkins/workspace/testdata" -recurse ")
```

And then output the results I do actually get a list of the folders in that directory.

Any idea for the cause of failure at this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've neglected to escape the `"` chars. *embedded* (nested) in your overall `"..."`-quoted command string as `\"`.

> `powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "gci -path "c:\jenkins\..." .... "`

```
                                                   ^              ^ must be \-escaped
```

However, given that you're not trying to reference *Groovy* variable values in your script, a simple workaround is to use `'...'` as the overall quoting, inside of which `"` can be used *without* escaping:

```
powershell returnStdout: true, script: 'gci -path "c:/jenkins/workspace/testdata" -recurse | where-object{ $_.Name -like "*testconfig.staging.json*"} | %{rename-item $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace("staging","local") }'
```

For even more flexibility, you can use a triple single-quoted string (typically used for defining multi-line string literals), in which you're free to use both `'` and `"` instances without escaping:

```
powershell returnStdout: true, script: '''
  gci -path "c:/jenkins/workspace/testdata" -recurse | where-object{ $_.Name -like "*testconfig.staging.json*"} | %{rename-item $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace("staging","local") }
'''
```

Note that the newlines (line breaks) after the opening `'''` and before the closing `'''` become part of the string, but in the context of interpreting the string as PowerShell source code that makes no difference.

---

If you do want to **incorporate Groovy variables or expressions** into your command string:

- you *must* use a *double-quoted* string
- and embed Groovy variable references / expression via `${...}`
- and escape all those `$` instances meant to be interpreted by *PowerShell* as `\$`.

For instance, to use Groovy variable `$variable` in the `.Replace()` call:

```
powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
  gci -path "c:/jenkins/workspace/testdata" -recurse | 
    where-object { \$_.Name -like "*testconfig.staging.json*" } |
      % { rename-item \$_.FullName \$_.FullName.Replace("${variable}","local") }
"""
```

The use of the *triple* double-quoted form again allows you to freely embed `"` instances inside the string.